# How to check (on Windows) if CPU is 64-bit compatible?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, cpu

I'm converting old Windows desktop machines from 2005-2009 into cheap Ubuntu Linux servers.  I want to know which ones can handle a 64-bit OS and which can't.   I read that some x86 CPUs are 64-bit compatible. The question is how to check.

Comment: Unless you need to handle more than 4gb of ram, 32 bit is prolly a better choice IMO, even with 64 bit capable systems.

Comment: @The Journeyman geek -- I went 64-bit because of [this quote from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit): "Unless you have specific reasons to choose 32-bit, we recommend 64-bit."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definitive method:

1. Download [CPUZ](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php)
2. Install and run it
3. Check the "Instructions" value for EM64T (if Intel) or AMD64 (if AMD).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm)

[image: SecurAble]

Run this utility and check the field "Maximum Bit Length"; it will show either 32 or 64. This utility is mainly used for checking if your CPU supports hardware virtualization, but it can be used for this purpose as well.