# How do I check whether my hardware is 64-bit capable in Windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm using a 32-bit operating system. How can I check if my hardware supports 64-bit?

Comment: yes, it would work fine.

Comment: the first result of a search for "Q8200" is intel's data sheet - http://ark.intel.com/products/36547/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q8200-(4M-Cache-2_33-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB) - which includes "64 bit instruction set"

Comment: Run [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) from Steve Gibson at grc.com.

Comment: Your CPU supports the upgrade. Every Core 2 CPU is 64-bit capable. Whether the rest of your components do, we can't really know. (But if they support Windows 7, they'll support 64-bit Windows 7.)

Comment: Anybody puzzled by the comments above should see http://superuser.com/questions/399482/how-to-know-whether-my-cpu-supports-a-64-bit-operating-system which was closed as a duplicate of this question.  Looks like the comments from that question were automatically migrated to this one.

Comment: @David Schwartz That means every pc capable of running Windows 7(32 or 64 bit) has 64 capability. Please let me know.

Comment: @Moshii I was only talking about his machine, which we know has a Core 2 CPU. If a machine has a 32-bit CPU, it will not support 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check (on Windows) if CPU is 64-bit compatible?](https://superuser.com/questions/143901/how-to-check-on-windows-if-cpu-is-64-bit-compatible)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I have machine, Intel Core 2 Duo, it is confirmed that 64-bit capable and I can run Windows 7 on my machine. So, can I install Windows 7 64-bit or Linux Ubuntu on my machine?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Install and run Securable, it will tell you. If you get the 64 max bit length, then yes your processor supports it.

http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

.

.
[image]

Comment: Both good answers, but I love Securable for its simplicity for the given task. And large font. ;)

Comment: grc. Still out and about , even in the current year. Haven't use that site in decades!

Comment: But that's for Windows. Do they do a Linux version?

Comment: Grc only has Windows utlities, check over here under Unix...https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ... or here...https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "64bit maximum bit length" is not a 64bit CPU. Support for over 4GB RAM is a 64bit CPU. . 64bit instructions don't help when a PageFile is needed to execute them....

Comment: From Windows Performance index shown that mine is 64-bit capable. Is that mean that my processor (or probably the motherboard?) capable for 64-bit?

Comment: I checked my machine using your software, and the result is as this:

Intel Core 2 Dua CPU / T7300@2000Hz --  
**64 Maximum Bit Length** -- 
**OFF Hardware D.E.P** --
**Locked ON Hardware Virtualization**

What is that mean? Can I install Windows or Linux Ubuntu 64 bit on my machine?

Comment: You can click on each of the three and get additional details.

Answer (score 29):

### For Windows 7 and above

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/15056/windows-7-32-64-bit-faq:

1. Open Performance Information and Tools: Clicking the `Start button` and then click `Control Panel`. In the search box `(Ctrl + E)`, type `Performance Information and Tools`, and then, in the list of results, click *Performance Information and Tools*
2. Click `View and print details`
3. In the `System` section, you can see whether or not you can run a 64-bit version of Windows under `64-bit capable`

---

Example:
[image: 64-bit capable]

Comment: since the last time i answered this question microsoft has provided a dedicated page for the same...
[Is my PC running the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/find-out-32-or-64-bit)

Comment: That tells you if you're **running** 32-bit or 64-bit Windows. Not if you *can* run 64-bit Windows.

Comment: thanks... that's right... the link in the comment does not server the intended purpose... the answer stands correct...

Comment: It was hoping the web-site would describe a way to see if my machine is *64-bit capable*.

Comment: Answer not valid for Windows XP.

Comment: If your PC's *Windows Experience Index* has [not yet been established](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMw8f.png), this method will require Administrator Rights.

Comment: From Windows Performance index shown that mine is 64-bit capable. Is that mean that my processor (or probably the motherboard?) capable for 64-bit? Appreciated your response.

Answer (score 7):

You can see whether you have a 64-bit or 32-bit CPU in Windows by opening the **System Information** window.

- If your **System Type** includes ***x86***, you have a **32-bit CPU**.
- If your **System Type** includes ***x64***, you have a **64-bit CPU**.

<sub>(*Note that having a 64-bit capable CPU is **NOT** the same as having a 64-bit version of Windows.*)</sub>

---

### Windows 10/8

1. Right click the **Start** button, then choose **Run**.
2. Type `msinfo32` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Windows 8 - System Information]

---

### Windows 7/Vista/XP

1. Click the **Start** button, then choose **Run**.
2. Type `msinfo32` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Windows 7 System Information]

---

#### Sources

- [Computer Hope - How to determine if you have a 64-bit or 32-bit CPU](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001121.htm)
- [Microsoft Support - Using System Information (Windows XP)](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/snap_msinfo32.mspx)
- [How-To Geek - How to Open the System Information Panel on Windows 10 or 8](https://www.howtogeek.com/196893/how-to-open-the-system-information-panel-on-windows-8/)

Answer (score 4):

Install [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), run and check out results. If you are unsure, post results (screenshot) to your question. There is no good way in Windows for determining that, except if your Windows is already 64bit. Check out for example [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/36088/how-can-i-find-out-whether-my-windows-is-32bit-or-64-bit).

Answer (score 4):

Another method to find out if your processor supports 32 or 64-bit:

1. Click on the Start menu
2. Click **Run** (or type `run` on Windows Vista/7 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Type `regedit` and press **OK**
4. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\CENTERALPROCESSOR\0`

Look at the `Identifier`, it should say contain "Intel64" or "Intel32".

Comment: `reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\CentralProcessor\0"` from Command Prompt when access to `regedit.exe` has been disabled.

Comment: Mine says `x86 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5`

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter what your current OS is - sysinfo, properties, etc., will only tell you what your current OS is. To find out whether your hardware is 64-bit capable, download and run [Microsoft's Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20).

The "[Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20)" should give you a full report on whether your system can run 32-bit and/or 64-bit. Any drivers can be downloaded, no issue there. A new Windows 7 package should come with both Windows 7  32-bit disk and 64-bit disk as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out "64-bit instruction set" as defined by Intel doesn't guarantee a 64-bit CPU. It refers to Windows 64 compatibility, as I remember IA-32e is not supported after 8.1. due to the hardware [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit) requirement.

This is where confusion reigns because Technet (and MSDN to lesser extent) imply Windows 64 is required to use over 4 GB of RAM, omitting the part about hardware support. It's not clear to end users.

Intel ARK maximum memory specifications are *n*GB for all 64-bit processors, but for the IA-32 family the "*n*GB" is replaced with "*n*bits", e.g. 32-bit support...

One way to find out is look up chipset specifications on Intel ARK. CPU hardware [DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection#Windows)/NX should ensure full compatibility as well.

The "virtual + physical" can translate to pagefile + RAM...it pays to check...

[image]

[image]

Typing *systeminfo* in a CMD prompt will also bring up specifications...

[image]

Or- *My Computer/Properties/Advanced/Environment Variables* if Intel64 or AMD64 is listed next to architecture you have a 64-bit hardware. :)

[image]