# How to know maximum ram that your H/W and Win version supports?

Tags: windows-7, memory

Hello All,
                 Firstly i DO NOT want to sound redundant and tedious here but is there a very simple way to actually know the maximum amount of RAM your laptop supports. 
    I have been reading a lot about the limitations on Win 32 bit and all.
    I use a 2 gb RAM on a WIN 7 32 bit OS and Dual core Processor.

And also if i install a 2GB with a 4GB RAM of the same clock speed, how would that affect the performance?

Comment: The manual for your motherboard will always have this information.  If its an OEM device then the OEM will provide the limit.  You can also verify what the chipset itself supports on AMD/Intel website.

Comment: There are two issues, the OS and the architecture.  You need to determine whether the motherboard/CPU are capable of handling 64 bits.  If not, the maximum RAM the computer can address is a little less than 4 GB unless there are design limitations on the number and size of the RAM modules that limit it to less than that.  You need to check the computer's hardware specs to determine these limits.  If the architecture is 64 bit capable, then you can typically install 4 GB or more, but a 32 bit OS will limit that (which can be solved by using a 64 bit OS).

Comment: This question technically isn't a duplicate of the question listed because that one is limited to the implications of a 32 bit OS.  This question could have hardware implications, also (see title).  It is likely a duplicate of one of the many questions that are computer-specific, but this question doesn't identify the computer.  The hardware issues are probably covered by this generic question: http://superuser.com/questions/18995/how-can-i-tell-what-ram-will-fit-my-computer

Comment: Well yeah, i have tried to keep this question as generic as possible, adding to it, a little of bit of specific computer  related question. So in all fairness, i would like it to be unmarked as duplicate(i'm new to the community, as is clear and hence, not very familiar with how this should be done).
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks much.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for the detailed explanation. Was very helpful

Comment: You are likely to find the information you need in existing answers to similar questions.  Check out the link to the duplicate message and the one in my comment.  Do a search on "maximum RAM" in the search box in the site's top border to see existing answers.  If you still need help, identify your computer in the question and clarify what you still need.

Comment: The answers to the question link against which my question has been marked duplicate, are at the very best, ambiguous.Instead, the link in your comment was much helpful and also this question http://superuser.com/questions/251014/how-to-check-whether-my-hardware-is-64-bit-capable-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Go to the website of the company that produced your machine and look there. They will have the specs.

Comment: Expandable MEMORY shows 16GB. So like i can upgrade irrespective of  the OS version?

Comment: You can upgrade but your OS will not be able use more than 4 Gig.

Comment: See the other answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have probably read somewhere, Windows 7 32-bit can only address 4 GB of memory as can be seen in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7) from Microsoft.

There is no *easy* way to tell how much memory your laptop supports, but you can usually find that information on the manufacturers website. Look up your specific make and model.

Kingston offers an easy-to-use [Memory Search](http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/options/) on their website, which has information on the most common laptop vendors.

As for combining 2 GB and 4 GB modules in the same laptop, that will not cause any problems, as long as the modules are both compatible with the hardware. Should your laptop support dual channel memory (which is not a normal feature on laptops) using memory modules of different size will simply disable this feature.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting and/or marking as accepted!

Comment: i really want to , but guess what, Stack Overflow doesn't really considers an UPVOTE from a person with less than 15 REPUTATION.
So much for the community! ;)