# Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: cpu, powershell, 64-bit, windows-10-upgrade

I want to know whether my PC will support 64 bit windows 10 pro or not?
Currently I'm using 32 bit widows 10 pro activated with digital license.

[settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASMjj.png)

[system information app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6XqT.png)

[Powershell sysinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av8zQ.png)

I've used coreinfo from sysinternals website and this is what it tells about my processor.
  "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
x86 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel"

Well, i'm confused  which info is correct shell says my processor is x64 family. Coreinfo says it is x86 family. settings page says under "system type" "x64 based processor" but system information app says under "system type" "x86 based PC"
Tell me if i need to provide more information.
I tried asking this in Microsoft community but not much help.
Its my first question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a Windows computer has a 64-bit CPU or OS](https://superuser.com/questions/208312/how-to-tell-if-a-windows-computer-has-a-64-bit-cpu-or-os)

Comment: Intel 64-bit extension has been available fore more than a decade, so obviously all Intel CPUs since Pentium 4 Prescott (except some early Atom and embedded CPUs) have 64-bit support

Answer (score 3):

You have a **64-bit** CPU. The Intel [ARK page for your CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95451/intel-core-i7-7500u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html) can confirm that it has the "Intel 64" instruction set. (Probably all Intel Core i3/i5/i7 are 64-bit.)

---

Both labels are technically correct, because "x64" (aka Intel x86_64 or amd64) is actually just a 64-bit variant of the previous "x86" (Intel i386/…/i686) architecture, as opposed to e.g. ARM or Itanium which are completely different worlds.

So it says "X86-based system" because the x64 CPU can run both x64 and x86 variants of Windows – but it cannot run e.g. Windows for IA64 (Itanium), which used to be a source of confusion.

Additionally, x64 systems have the same Windows licensing rules as x86 systems did; however ARM systems have different licensing.

Comment: What is ARM ???

Comment: Should go for installing 64 bit or not?

Comment: ARM is a CPU architecture commonly used on phones and tablets.

Comment: You're basically wasting 6 GB of RAM if you use a 32-bit OS, so yes.

Comment: Thanks you've helped a lot.but one more question. how do i know that all my hardware has 64 bit drivers available to run windows 10 64 bit

Comment: @CopperGolie https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/vostro-14-3468-laptop/drivers

It has compatible drivers, I don't know how you still have a 32-bit OS.

Comment: @CaldeiraG He probably got an inplace upgrade from 32-bit Win7 or Win8. In that case you will also get a 32-bit Win10. But you can just re-install from scratch with the 64-bit version and the Win10 license will still be valid (provided it was linked to a Microsoft Account off course).

Comment: @Tonny Actually i got the laptop from a governmental organization as a prize and it came pre-installed with windows 10 pro 32-bit.

Comment: @CopperGolie I see. I hope that the laptop has a Windows 10 license sticker or has a license key embedded in the Bios. If it hasn't you will have to obtain a new license for this system for a 64-bit re-install. (If you have a Win7 or later license from an unused machine that can sometimes be used as well.)

Comment: @Tonny where to check for the license sticker and the key

Comment: @CopperGolie Sticker (if present) should be on the outside of the case. In some cases it is on the inside of the case or a panel (desktop/tower). Laptops sometimes have it inside as well (under the battery is common). But it should be in an easily accessible place, not requiring tools to access. For a Bios based license sometimes the license information is shown in the Bios setup itself. If it isn't there exist programs that you can run in Windows which reveal the current license, but of the top of my head I can't remember which program(s) that would be.

Comment: @Tonny Ah yes it has a sticker below the laptop but it is very much worn out and not readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your PC supports a 64-bit operating system.
You can check this by doing a few different methods.

In Windows 10 and Windows 8.1
Go to the **Settings** (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>). Then **System** > **About**.
At the right, under **Device specifications**, see **System type**.

In here if you see..,

- **64-bit operating system, x64-based processor** - This means your CPU supports 64-bit and you already have the 64-bit version of
  Windows.
- **32-bit operating system, x64-based processor** - This means your CPU supports 64-bit, but you have installed the 32-bit version of
  Windows.
- **32-bit operating system, x86-based processor** - This means your processor doesn't support 64-bit and you have the 32-bit version of
  Windows installed.

You can also check this by checking your process specification.
Intel® Core™ i7-7500U Processor - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95451/intel-core-i7-7500u-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html

> ```
>   Advanced Technologies           
>  ----------------------- -------- 
>   Intel® 64 ‡             Yes     
>   Instruction Set         64-bit
> ```

It is also worth noting that if you're using the 32-bit operating system (OS), it can only handle 4GB of memory. So that means, since you have an 8GB of RAM, you're wasting your resource by using a 32-bit Operating system. So, in your case, it's recommended to use a 64-bit OS. However, to install a 64-bit OS, you have to manually reinstall 64-bit OS. You cannot upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit.

> **Physical Memory Limits: Windows 10**
>
> The following table specifies the limits on physical memory for
>   Windows 10.
>
> ```
> +----------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
> |             Version              | Limit on X86  | Limit on X64 |
> +----------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
> | Windows 10 Enterprise            | 4 GB          | 6 TB         |
> | Windows 10 Education             | 4 GB          | 2 TB         |
> | Windows 10 Pro for Workstations  | 4 GB          | 6 TB         |
> | Windows 10 Pro                   | 4 GB          | 2 TB         |
> | Windows 10 Home                  | 4 GB          | 128 GB       |
> +----------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
> ```

Source: [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical_memory_limits_windows_10%20Reply)

---

<sup>Related

 - [How do I check whether my hardware is 64-bit capable in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/251014/485660)

 - [How to check (on Windows) if CPU is 64-bit compatible?](https://superuser.com/q/143901/485660)

 - [How much memory can be accessed by a 32-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8869563/6327676)</sup>

Reference
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15056/windows-32-64-bit-faq
- https://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/
- [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases#physical_memory_limits_windows_10%20Reply)